# Angular- Material table sorting not working in proper way

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I'm creating a table that should sort by file name and date I followed the Angular Material documentation for this purpose but is not working, it's not showing any errors in the compiler or the browser console, the table looks like this:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="File">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> File </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element" data-label="File"> {{element.fileName}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Date">
        <mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element" data-label="Date"> {{element.date}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Extension">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Extension</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element" data-label="Extension"> {{element.extension}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>



      <ng-container matColumnDef="View">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element" data-label="View"> <a href="{{element.url}}" target="_blank" class="green-text"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a></mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Delete">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element" data-label="Delete"> <a class="red-text"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></a></mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

and this is my ts code

```
export class FilesComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['File', 'Extension', 'Date', 'View', 'Delete'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Files>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  data = ELEMENT_DATA;
  selects: any;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  constructor(private addFile: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Materialize();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  Materialize() {
    this.selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    M.FormSelect.init(this.selects);
  }

  changeFiles(value) {
    console.log('option:', value);
    switch (parseInt(value)) {
      case 1:
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Files>(ELEMENT_DATA);
        break;
      case 2:
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Files>(Charts);
        break;
      case 3:
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Files>(Documents);
        break;
      default:
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Files>(ELEMENT_DATA);
        break;
    }
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}
```

event the sort header it's applied and the styles (the arrows for the sort) appear in the table the data does not sort.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz link for above code?

Comment: here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5ehdx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

matColumnDef name and *matCellDef actual value name should be same

**In component.html**

Change

`<ng-container matColumnDef="File">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> File </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element" data-label="File"> {{element.fileName}} </mat-cell></ng-container>`

to

`<ng-container matColumnDef="fileName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> File </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element" data-label="File"> {{element.fileName}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>`

**In ts:**

change

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['File', 'Extension', 'Date', 'View', 'Delete'];
```

to

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['fileName', 'Extension', 'Date', 'View', 'Delete'];
```

Comment: worked for me!!! I used the same object property name in displayedColums array and matColumnDef and works it. Thanks.

Comment: Tried sooo many things. This resolved it when nothing else did. Resolved after one hour, could have been many more.

Answer (score 1):

@user12129132's answer will work for normal sorting ( You need to change the field values in the datasource to match the field values in the column definitions and also use the same in matColumn definition) but you have filename with numbers in it, it wont be sorted properly.For that purpose we can use  sortingDataAccessor.

See the working version here - Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g4svyj

```
ngAfterViewInit() {    
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (data, attribute) => {
        let formattedData=data[attribute]
        if(attribute=="fileName"){  
            formattedData=parseInt(formattedData.match(/(\d)*$/)[0]);
        }
        return formattedData;
    };
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the moment i'm using only fake data but I'll have this in mind for when they give me the real data

Comment: I only upvoted this because the afterviewInit life cycle is important to get the sorting  -and also de paginator- working when you fetch the data through http for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `MatSortModule` to the imports array in `app.module.ts`